# IllegalArgumentException in class: testapp.main.model.Users, setter method of property: id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate with Spring Boot and configured cfg.xml and hbm.xml files properly and they are working fine with get method, but getting this error if try to save record.

[image: Screenshot of Error and code]

Attached users.hbm.xml for the reference

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "https://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="moneytracker.main.model.Users" table="USERS">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="email" type="java.lang.String" unique="true">
            <column name="email"/>
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="hash_password"/>
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="first_name"/>
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="last_name"/>
        </property>
        <property name="secretQuestion" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="secret_question"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this is the code for saving,

```
  public Users saveUser(Users user) {
        Users _user = new Users();
        _user.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        _user.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        _user.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        _user.setSecretQuestion(user.getSecretQuestion());
        _user.setPassword(user.getPassword());

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        try {
            session.save(_user);
            System.out.println("USER ID = " + _user.getId());

            tx.commit();
            session.close();
            return _user;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Error while saving: " + ex);
            throw new PersistenceException(ex);
        }
    }
```